# API-based service for posting video to social media

Tags: api, social-networks

We are looking at creating a cloud-based service that will process video. As part of this, we're looking to post the resultant video to a number of social media channels. Obviously they all have their own APIs, so we could integrate with each of them separately, but I was wondering if there exists a service that could do this bit for us, so that we don't have to keep on top of the changes to the various APIs?

I've found lots of apps that do so, but they all seem to be based around a dashboard for creating the content, whereas we need an API to which we can post the video generated by our system.

Requirements:

- API to which we can post
- Ability to post to Facebook, Twitter, Youtube, Instagram (when their video API becomes available)
- Either webservice, or something we can run on AWS/Docker/etc